# No image is shown from buttonImage, the JS widget for my datepicker calendar icon

Tags: javascript

I am creating a page where users can select date from picking it from calendar icon.

I tried the following code but the calendar icon didn't show up.
What's the problem tho? Thanks in advance!

```
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
showOn: "both",
buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonText: "Select date"
});
} );
```

[reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWx2l.png)
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZR38.png)

Comment: Have you verified that the path to `buttonImage` is correct?

Comment: I copied the path and pasted it in the buttonImage. Is that how we verified?

Comment: It is solved now. Thanks!